# How to set a separate billing and shipping address using PayPal PHP REST SDK?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Trying to send a separate billing and shipping address when creating a payment using the REST api for paypal.

I can successfully create a shipping address:

```
$shipping_address = new ShippingAddress();
$shipping_address->setCity('XXXXXX');
$shipping_address->setCountryCode('XX');
$shipping_address->setPostalCode('111111');
$shipping_address->setLine1('9811 XXXXXX Lane');
$shipping_address->setLine2('Suite 100');
$shipping_address->setState('XXXXXX');
$shipping_address->setRecipientName('Mark XXXXXX');

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setShippingAddress($shipping_address);
```

When I do this it ALSO replicated this address to billing. But I cannot figure out how to send a SEPARATE address to pre-populate the billing information?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't include real personal data in your posts.

Comment: I've removed personal information from your post. Be it yours, or someone else's, please omit them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the BillingInfo class might provide what you need.

After creating the BillingInfo object, add it to the Invoice object.